# Dynamically bound menu

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i'm noobie on WPF.
i have this Admin menu include 'manage A','manage B','manage C'

in my XAML

```
<MenuItem Header="_Admin" Name="adminMenuItem" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsAdmin, Mode=OneWay,}" >

 <MenuItem Header="manage A" Command="ShowTab" />
 <MenuItem Header="manage B" Command="ShowTab" />
 <MenuItem Header="manage C" Command="ShowTab" />            

</MenuItem>
```

in my mainWindow.cs code,

```cs
private void ShowTab(MenuItem menuItem)
{
    if (menuItem.Header = "manage A")
        showTabA();
    if (menuItem.Header = "manage B")
        showTabB();
    if (menuItem.Header = "manage C")
        showTabC();
}
```

can i bind menuitem with commands like that? if not, what's the best way to get the value from different menu items.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a CommandParameter in the MenuItems which identifies the tab, and get that value from the `ExecutedRoutedEventArgs.Parameter` property, it's cleaner than using the header at the very least.